# PostgreSQL unique by two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table

The table:

```
id SERIAL, 
certificates_path VARCHAR,
voyages_path VARCHAR,
general_path VARCHAR,
user INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
vessel INTEGER REFERENCES vessels(id);
```

Each users has it's own set of paths for each vessels.

`certificates_path`, `voyages_path` and `general_path` hold standard Linux/Windows file paths.

I need to `CREATE TABLE` and ensure that only one record for each user-vessel combination would exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a unique constraint:

```
create table . . . (
    . . . ,
    constraint unq_t_paths unique (user, vessel)
);
```